# Quotactl Block size

Tags: linux, api

I am using quotactl package for quota management on my SUSE linux setup. How can I programatically find the blocksize in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk quota blocksize is always `BLOCK_SIZE`, defined in `sys/mount.h`.